# How to select a dojo TabBarButton?

Tags: select, button, dojo, tabbar

i have a view called divChal. When i change the view to that i also want to change the selected Button in the tabbar to the button with the id tabBarButtonChal.
i tried it like this, which doesn't work.

```
var divChal = dijit.registry.byId("divChal");
dojo.aspect.after(divChal,"onBeforeTransitionIn", function(){
   var tabBarButtonChal = dijit.registry.byId("tabBarButtonChal");
   tabBarButtonChal.select();
});
```

greets Tom

Comment: What do you mean by selected?  Do you mean focus?  Can you edit the question and post the 'view' you are talking about?  (Like HTML)

Comment: i alreay solevd the problem. I am usin dojo 1.8.x so the right way to highlight a tabbarbutton is dijit.registry.byId("BUTTONNAME").set('selected', true);

Answer (score 0):

This way to set a property on a node is to evoke `set(property, value)` on it:

```
dojo.aspect.after(divChal,"onBeforeTransitionIn", function(){
   dijit.registry.byId("tabBarButtonChal").set('selected', true);
});
```